# How to preserve selections of user during screen transitions in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, state

I have a bottom navigation bar which includes home button, screen1 button and screen2 button. User is making some selections on home screen.
After that he taps the screen1 button on bottom navigation bar and goes to screen 1. 
Then in order to return home screen, he taps home button. But home screen rebuild and all information has gone.
I tried AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin  but it is not working. My code sample is below. Is there any mistake here?

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {

@override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
```

Comment: What kind of information do you want to persist?

Comment: I have a listview whic includes buttons. User taps and select some of them. I keep how many button selected and also change the color of the selected buttons. I want to maintain selected buttons in my listview when user return to home screen.

Comment: so do you have list of model?

Comment: yes, I have a listview component

Comment: No I mean like List<Object> where render objects one by one

Comment: for now, I have a sample list and render in my listview component which is a different file from home screen. Should I do this AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin stuff in there?

Comment: I did it in my listview class, but still it is not working